# Unzip из-под Midnight commander работает медленно. Как ускорить?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, zip, mc

Есть сервера на базе Centos 6 или 7, заметил такую особенность.

Приходится изредка закидывать на сервер присланный zip-файл и распаковывать его на сервере.

Поддержки zip штатно нет, приходится сначала ставить `sudo yum install unzip`, после чего можно как из командной строки разархивировать (`unzip -d /where_to_unizp/ filename_to_unzip.zip`), так и midnight commander'ом.

И вот что странно. Почему-то mc распаковывает неправдоподобно долго. Из командной строки - ну пара секунд, а в mc -- тот же самый файл может показывать запредельные цифры:

> ```
> ├──────────────── Всего: 196K/721M  ───────────────────┤
> │ Обработано файлов: 83/50564                          │
> │ Время: 0:03:08 ETA 197:06:15 (1,04 кб/с)             │
> ```

Отчего так и можно ли это как-то ускорить?

У меня предположение, что это никак не связано с ключами распаковки, а с тем, что это через какие-то промежуточные буферы сначала куда-нибудь распаковывается.

Comment: Не надо пользоваться поделием под названием mc, никогда.

Comment: @0andriy, былаб альтенатива. 
в тоталкомандере было копирование прямым доступом, ускорялся в 5 раз)

Comment: Проблема в том, что мс распаковывает архивы в два этапа - на первом этапе он составляет список файлов, а на втором - для каждого отдельного файла отдельно вызывает распаковщик. Для чего так сделано - не знаю. Подозреваю - на тот случай, если в архиве лежат архивы. Эта проблема есть при распаковке архивов всех типов, а не только зипованых. Так что большие архивы я всегда распаковываю либо из командной строки, либо штатным распаковщиком из меню.

Comment: @Sergey ваш комментарий вполне годится на роль одного из ответов.

Comment: не только архивы, любая vfs в mc работет очень медленно

Comment: из опыта скажу, что zip - зло. это совсем не пакет по умолчанию на Linux серверах. tar -czf, tar -xzf длжно стать мантрой админа.

Comment: @Hellseher Я не стал вписывать это в вопрос, но как я был зол, когда мне с дебиана присылал "их" сотрудник два раза битые .tar.gz на 80 мб, а потом прислали zip на 1,5 гига. Можно ругать и за кривые руки или хватилить за то, что в итоге всё же справились.

Answer (score 2):

Параметр в ini файле mc поставь true, будет чуток быстрей. По умолчанию:

```
preallocate_space=false
```