# Как в linux запаковать с паролем?

Tags: linux, bash, защита, архивация

Пишу небольшой sh-скрипт для архивирования папок на яндекс:диск и задумался о том, что `tar -cvzf` не поддерживает создание пароля, а складывать архивы с серверов на облако как-то нет желания.

Как  можно запаковать каталог под линукс с использованием пароля? Только вариант "ставить zip/unzip"?
Требований по скорости/сжатию нет (я не сжимаю вообще при архивировании), а шифрование должно быть достаточно стойким для 2019, а не какие-то древние/поломанные давно алгоритмы.

Comment: Вроде как tar  в чистом виде не поддерживает ни сжатие ни шифрование

Comment: Чем не устраивает zip/unzip? Вроде специально не ставил, стоит по умолчанию. [Здесь](https://superuser.com/questions/162624/how-to-password-protect-gzip-files-on-the-command-line), например,  предлагают поделить задачу.

Comment: ключевая идея, как и везде в `*nix`'ах в том, что архивирование, сжиматие и шифровка — это три разные задачи, так что их должны выполнять разные утилиты... ИМХО для [полу]автоматизированного бекапа практичней всего будет настроить `gpg` и шифровать им после/во время упаковки... само собой, здесь будет не пароль, а ключ... а так — есть много утилиток разной степени ненужности, но вполне можно даже штатным `openssl`'ем обойтись...

Comment: 7z вроде поддерживает какой-то там пароль. Правда, он его вроде читает только из аргумента командной строки, что само по себе не очень безопасно

Comment: Ну и gpg никто не отменял, в нём тоже есть шифрование файлов с паролем

Comment: @0xdb пожалуй, устраивает, хотя у меня [как-то был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/697162/213987) осадочек. Этот вариант просто мне в голову самому пришёл, хотел понять, нет ли какого-то более стандартного пути. Вот, кстати в комментах упомянули gpg  - он у меня есть в штатной поставке Centos6, а zip кстати нету почему-то.

Comment: @AK Просто поставте и попорбуйте. "Стандартный" варианты в ссылке в моём предыдущем комментарии, почти 1:1 с коментарием  Fat-Zer.

Comment: можно симметрично зашифровать zip-ом, 7zip-ом, openssl-ем и т.п., можно ассиметрично зашифровать gpg, openssl-ем (например, [используя openssh rsa-ключ](http://blog.barak.in/2013/03/encrypt-decrypt-with-openssh-rsa-keys.html))

Comment: gpg тоже умеет симметрично шифровать

Comment: А на яндекс льёшь как? Через `curl+webdav`?

Comment: @donRumata [yum install yandex-disk](https://yandex.ru/support/disk/cli-clients.html)

Comment: Афигеть! Как-то пропустил, что у них есть cli. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: я подобную задачу решал так: 1)архивировал,  2)шифровал открытым ключом PGP  3)монтировал davfs2 4)копировал 5)отмонтровал

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если задача стоит, только защитить содержимое паролем, то можно воспользоваться парой утилит *zip/unzip*.

```
zip -e <file_name.zip> <list_of_files>
```

С опцией `-e` утилита запросит задать пароль.
Смотри:  `$ man zip` и  `$ man unzip` для справки по другим опциям.

Рабочий пример:

```sh
$ touch file{1,2,3}.txt
$ zip -e file.zip file*
Enter password:
Verify password:
  adding: file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file2.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file3.txt (stored 0%)

$ rm file[123].txt
$ unzip file.zip
Archive:  file.zip
[file.zip] file1.txt password:
 extracting: file1.txt
 extracting: file2.txt
 extracting: file3.txt
```